# JDBC-ODBC Connection

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, odbc, jdbc-odbc

I am trying to connect MS Access with Java
Below is the error message

java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Code-

```
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");      
    String database = "jdbc:odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)};DSN=C:\\ST\\BillingTrackerDB.mdb";
   Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", "");
```

Comment: What do you understand by the exception? *Data source name not found*

Comment: Where is the `data-source-name` defined in the database url?

Comment: It might help you [What Is the JDBC URL Supported by the Bridge?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/bridge.doc.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)}
```

is an invalid ODBC driver name for Access; it is missing a space. The correct name is

```
DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of Java are you using?  In Java 8, I was unable to use the JDBC-ODBC bridge [as it has been removed in JDK 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html).  What I have found to use in place of the JDBC-ODBC bridge for connecting to Access Databases is a pure Java solution called [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html).  It has done everything I needed, so far.